# Scaling image with Core Image is cropping instead of scaling

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-image, swift4.2

I have a function that is supposed to scale an image using Core Image filters. It takes an NSImage and a dimension number as arguments and returns a scaled NSImage. I have been using: [Processing an Image Using Built-in Filters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/processing_an_image_using_built-in_filters)
as a reference. The code appears to be cropping the image instead of resizing it. I swear I had it working at one point, so where have I gone wrong?

```
func imageCIScale(_ image: NSImage, dimension: CGFloat) -> NSImage? {
    guard let data = image.tiffRepresentation,
        let scaleFilter = CIFilter(name: "CILanczosScaleTransform"),
        let ciImage = CIImage(data: data)
    else {
        print("Failure! Abject failure! Couldn't even get started")
        return nil
    }

    let scaleFactor = dimension / image.size.height

    scaleFilter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    scaleFilter.setValue(scaleFactor, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)
    scaleFilter.setValue(1.0, forKey: kCIInputAspectRatioKey)
    let outputImage = scaleFilter.outputImage

    let context = CIContext()
    guard let scaledImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: outputImage!.extent) else {
        print("Failed to create CGImage")
        return nil
    }

    return NSImage(cgImage: scaledImage, size: NSZeroSize)
}
```

The function would be called like:

```
let myScaledNSImage = imageCIScale(myOriginalNSImage, dimension: 32.0)
```

and should result in a 32 x 32 Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a good night's sleep I see what's wrong. I'm using the wrong image source when creating the CG Image

```
let scaledImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: outputImage!.extent)
```

should be

```
let scaledImage = context.createCGImage(outputImage!, from: outputImage!.extent)
```

or maybe more like

```
let context = CIContext()
guard let outputImage = scaleFilter.outputImage,
      let scaledImage = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent)
else {
    print("Failed to create CGImage")
    return nil
}
```

I'll leave the question up because, once corrected, I think it's a reasonable example for image scaling in Swift 4.2 in a Mac OS context.